# New to python. I need help assigning numerical values to an email list

Tags: python, list, email, numbers, assign

I am currently taking my first python class and I need help assigning numbers to an email when it is added to my list of emails. That way when someone wants to remove an email from the list, they can see what number the email is assigned to and just type in the number. I will provide my code, and a video of what the final product should look like.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWTpdMaxTvI&ab_channel=JenniferBailey

P.S. I don't know all the technical terms so I hope that made sense. Thanks!

```
menu = 0
list = []
while menu < 4:
    print(" 1 to add an email\n 2 to remove an email\n 3 to print list\n 4 to EXIT menu")
    print("")
    menu = int(input("Enter: "))
    print("")
    if menu == 1:
        enter_email = input("What is the email: ")
        list.insert(1, enter_email)
        print("")
        print("The email:", enter_email, "was successfully added to the list")
        print("")
    elif menu == 2:
        remove_email = input("What email would you like to remove: ")
        if remove_email in list:
            list.remove(remove_email)
            print("")
            print("The email, ", remove_email, ", was removed from the list")
            print("")
        else:
            print("")
            print("That email does not exist")
            print("")
    elif menu == 3:
            email_list = ', '.join(str(item) for item in list)
            print("")
            print(email_list)
            print("")
    elif menu == 4:
        print("Exited successfully, have a nice day")
```

Have not tried much and don't really know where to start.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Use `enumerate(list)` to get the indexes of each of the list elements, and print that as a menu. Then the user can type the index number and you can use `list[number]` to access that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salvatore!
Nice code, I think you are pretty close to the solution. In Python, there is a built-in function called enumerate that assign automatically a number to have a counter within a list [a link](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

In your code, I would add something like this:

*Note I just changed the code when the variable menu equals 3

```
menu = 0
list = []
while menu < 4:
    print(" 1 to add an email\n 2 to remove an email\n 3 to print list\n 4 to EXIT menu")
    print("")
    menu = int(input("Enter: "))
    print("")
    if menu == 1:
        enter_email = input("What is the email: ")
        list.insert(1, enter_email)
        print("")
        print("The email:", enter_email, "was successfully added to the list")
        print("")
    elif menu == 2:
        remove_email = input("What email would you like to remove: ")
        if remove_email in list:
            list.remove(remove_email)
            print("")
            print("The email, ", remove_email, ", was removed from the list")
            print("")
        else:
            print("")
            print("That email does not exist")
            print("")
    elif menu == 3:
      for counter, value in enumerate(list):
        print(counter, value)
        print("")
    elif menu == 4:
        print("Exited successfully, have a nice day")
```

Hope it can help you!!!

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. I have another question. How should I approach having the user remove the email. I want a number assigned to the entered email which you have helped me with, but how should I do that, with a loop?